# Error compiling nginx with passenger support

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby, compile, passenger

I've just installed passenger by:

```
gem install passenger
cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2
env NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/rake nginx:clean nginx RELEASE=yes
```

Then edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

Then `apt-get update`, `cd /var/tmp` and `apt-get source nginx`. Added `--add-module=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/src/nginx_module \` to `debian\rules` at the right place.

The problem comes when compiling nginx with passenger module support:

```
apt-get build-dep nginx
dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

```
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie -ldl -lpthread -lpthread -lcrypt /var/tmp/ngx_pagespeed-1.12.34.2-beta/psol/lib/Release/linux/x64/pagespeed_automatic.a -lstdc++ -lrt -pthread -lm -lexpat /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Exceptions.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/SystemTime.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtils.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/StrIntUtilsNoStrictAliasing.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/IOUtils.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/WatchdogLauncher.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/AppTypes.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Utils/CachedFileStat.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/UnionStationFilterSupport.o /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lrt -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lGeoIP \
-Wl,-E
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/buildout/common/libpassenger_common/Logging.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
objs/Makefile:344: recipe for target 'objs/nginx' failed
make[2]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/t/nginx-1.10.3/debian/build-nginx'
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'build' failed
make[1]: *** [build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/t/nginx-1.10.3/debian/build-nginx'
debian/rules:60: recipe for target 'build-arch.nginx' failed
make: *** [build-arch.nginx] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

This is the output of `passenger-config --nginx-addon-dir`:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/src/nginx_module
```

The curious thing is if i try to compile nginx from source through `passenger-install-nginx-module` everything works fine.

Anyway, does any one know how could i fix this issue? For me, compiling nginx following the mentioned procedure is a must. I would like to be able to follow the above procedure while fixing the issue.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i edited `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/cxx_portability.rb` and replaced this line `flags << "-fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED"` by `flags << "-fvisibility=hidden -DVISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE_SUPPORTED -fPIC"`. Then compiled passenger by running the previous rake command, `env NOEXEC_DISABLE=1 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/rake nginx:clean nginx RELEASE=yes`.